# I need to put two threads in java and have one part of my code wait for the other to end

Tags: java, multithreading

Good I have never used threads in java and what happens to me is that I try to call a class and then do something that changes some values ​​of the class, but what happens that changes the values ​​before unfortunately, and I would need to put two threads In java to be able to tell the values ​​that I want to change, wait until the class finishes doing its function, I pass the code and I tell you what I want to do. Thank you.

```
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            try {
                // capa transparente
                if (auxContadorZoom < 3 && auxContadorZoom >= 0) {
                    zoom.aumentar(100);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 400; j++) {
                            image2.setRGB(i, j, zoom.enviar().getRGB(i, j));
                        }
                    }
                    label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(zoom.enviar()));
                    label2.removeAll();
                    label2.add(zoom);
                    label2.repaint();
                    auxContadorZoom++;
                }

                // capa fondo
                if (auxContadorZoom1 < 3 && auxContadorZoom1 >= 0) {
                    zoom1.aumentar(100);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 400; j++) {
                            image.setRGB(i, j, zoom1.enviar().getRGB(i, j));
                        }
                    }
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(zoom1.enviar()));
                    label.removeAll();
                    label.add(zoom1);
                    label.repaint();
                    auxContadorZoom1++;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        //////This is where I want the 2 thread to wait for me to do this so that the zoom class finishes doing its things that I have previously sent
            zoom1.activarBoolTrue();
            zoom.activarBoolTrue();
        }
```

Comment: Is `mouseClicked` being called by one of the two threads or is it being called by a mouse click?

Comment: is calling by a click, what I want is to do with threads to control it. Thank you

Comment: OK. I'll add an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You should use a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`

`synchronized` isn't appropriate since it will have the two threads blocking each other every time they run their code. `wait`/`notify` isn't appropriate since it will have the two threads waiting until the GUI event thread runs `mouseClicked`, which means that your two threads will completely freeze up until someone clicks the relevant GUI element rather than running freely whenever `mouseClicked` isn't in the special section you want to protect.

Since you want to block the two threads only when the separate GUI event thread calls the `mouseClicked` method and not have the other two threads blocking each other, a [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) will work nicely.

## Implementing it in your example

At the top of the file (just under the `package` statement if you have one) containing the class that contains the `mouseClicked` method:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;
```

At the top of the class where you are defining variables:

```java
public class … {
    public static final ReentrantReadWriteLock mouseClickedLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
```

In the `mouseClicked` method when you want to stop the other two threads, lock the `writeLock`, try to execute your code, then unlock the `writeLock`:

```java
        //////This is where I want the 2 thread to wait for me to do this so that the zoom class finishes doing its things that I have previously sent
            mouseClickedLock.writeLock().lock();
            try {
                zoom1.activarBoolTrue();
                zoom.activarBoolTrue();
            } finally {
                mouseClickedLock.writeLock().unlock();
            }
```

In the two threads, when you're doing something that shouldn't interrupt that special section of the `mouseClicked` method, lock a `readLock`, try to execute your code, then unlock that `readLock`:

```java
mouseClickedLock.readLock().lock();
try {
    // Your code here
} finally {
    mouseClickedLock.readLock().unlock();
}
```

Make sure that the code using a read lock doesn't take that long to execute, since it will block `mouseClicked`'s special section until the read lock is unlocked. If a thread has a loop where it does the same thing over and over again, you should probably lock and unlock ***inside*** that loop so that it's waiting for one iteration of the loop to complete rather than all iterations.

Now the two threads can do what they want whenever they want to, except when the `mouseClicked` method's special section is executing, where they will wait until that's finished.

## Speed things up with a `StampedLock` if you start using many more threads

If you begin to have many more threads than just two threads and the GUI event thread, a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` can become slow. You can use a [`StampedLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html) instead to speed things up.

It's a little more complicated to use, since you have to store a `long` value called a stamp in order to later unlock the `StampedLock` and since you can't have the same thread lock a `StampedLock` twice without unlocking it in between the two lockings (i.e., it's not a [reentrant lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex)) or else your program or some of its threads might permanently freeze up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about locks? You need to synchronize on a lock.

---

Create a lock object with `new Object()`, like:

```
Object lock = new Object();
```

and then use `synchronized` around code sections that should wait for each other, like:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    …
}
```

Make sure the threads can have access to that lock object.

---

Also, you can use a thread's `join` method to wait for that thread to finish.

Comment: How can I use it properly?

Comment: This will cause the two external threads to block each other, rather than merely causing the `mouseClicked` method to block the two threads when part of it is executing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wait()/notify()` which are designed to block (release) a thread until (when) a specific condition is met, or `join()` which allows one thread to wait until another thread completes its execution.

A possible solution would be sharing a common lock between two threads, say for example *Thread-A* and *Thread-B*. After some processing in *Thread-A*, call `wait()` on a shared lock and thus *Thread-A* is waiting. When *Thread-B* finishes its calculation, call `notifyAll()` on the same lock, and thus *Thread-A* resumes its processing.

```
final Object lock = new Object();
```

**Thread-A**

```
boolean isWorkDone = false;

// Do some processing here!

synchronized (lock) {
    try {
        while (!isWorkDone) {
            lock.wait();   // Thread-A waits here
        }

        isWorkDone = true;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
    } 
}

// Do rest of the processing here!
```

**Thread-B**

```
// Do your processing here.  

synchronized (lock) {
    lock.notifyAll(); // notify Thread-A that processing is done!
}
```

Comment: the lock can be a method?

Comment: The two threads are external to the `mouseClicked` method in the question. `synchronized` isn't a valid solution since it causes the two threads to block each other when only the `mouseClicked` thread needs to block the two other threads.